# Having trouble installing old school runescape

Tags: runescape

So I have been trying to get OSRS running and continue to run into an issue. I have been using guides online that have say to run

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:hikariknight/unix-runescape-client
```

Then

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And finally

```
sudo apt-get install unix-runescape-client
```

And it gives me

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 unix-runescape-client : Depends: open-6-jre but it is not installable or
openjdk-7-jre but it is not installable
```

I'm just starting out with Ubuntu and I can't seem to find a fix for this issue. Any help would be welcomed greatly.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to use Webup8 Oracle Java8 Installer

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java -y
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

To automatically set up the Java 8 environment variables

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

Check It

```
java -version
```

Then try run the install as you did before. This should help :-)

Comment: This won't provide any of the required `open-6-jre` or `openjdk-7-jre` packages. -1